# Architecture pattern for displaying a list with details in flutter Bloc

Tags: database, flutter, repository, bloc

I am building an application in flutter using the bloc architecture and I really like it.

For my application I need to manage lists of data. 4 different types. They share common attributes: name and description. I essentially need the 4 lists to be the same but differ what happens when the user taps on them.

The shared functionality is adding an item (which requires the user to fill in name and possible description), deleting and tapping on an item to go to a more detailed view where the user can edit the details(different for every entity, for example some might have a list of colors while others dont).
For the generic list i have currently defined a cubit and repo (these attributes are shared among all entities):

```
class CrudListBloc extends Bloc<CrudListEvent, CrudListState> {
  final CrudListRepo repo;

  CrudListBloc(this.repo) : super(CrudListEmpty()) {
    on<CrudListAdd>(_addItem);
    on<CrudListDelete>(_deleteItem);
    on<CrudListLoad>(_loadItems);
  }
}
```

```
abstract class CrudListRepo {
  Future<List<CrudListItem>> getAllItems();

  Future<String> addItem(String name, String? description);
}
```

```
class CrudListItem extends Equatable {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String? description;

  const CrudListItem({required this.id, required this.name, this.description});

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [id, name, description];
}
```

The approach I had in mind would allow the user of this bloc to supply a repo which gets just the names and ids and descriptions of the underlying data. And the crudlistbloc tells the underlying repo to create a new empty element with the supplied name and description. The underlying repo then returns id. Upon going to the detail view the id of the tapped element is passed and the full object can be retrieved from the specific entity repo.

What I'm struggling with is the following: We can easily create an empty element given an ID and name for any of the 4 entities in my application. So we could directly write the item created by the crudlistrepo to a repository of type T. But fetching just the name and ID of all elements can be easy or hard depending on the underlying implementation. If we were to use SQL we could just select name and ID and call it a day. But if the underlying data source is firebase we would have to create a seperate collection for just the names and ids and duplicate them.

Therefore I am  doubting if it is not more appropriate to just fetch all objects of type T upon loading the list. It feels wrong to store the same data twice. We could make the crudlist of type CrudList where we put a bound on T to have a name and id. This could potentially increase loading times of the list when T's are very large but would work with all databases and avoid duplication and make the implementation more straightforward.

Which approach would you suggest or is there something better I'm not seeing altogether? Thanks a lot!

I tried hard to think about the solution, but I am quite new to the Bloc architecture and need some advice for this (I expect quite common) problem.

Comment: It is not clear what is the object of the question. BLoC is a state-management framework

Answer (score 1):

Your challenge revolves around the database management decision of normalization vs. denormalization.

**Normalization:**

- Pros: Maintains data integrity with a single data source and is space-efficient.
- Cons: Might need complex queries or more reads for full data.

**Denormalization:**

- Pros: Offers fast reads and straightforward queries, especially beneficial in Firebase for optimized read operations due to its cost structure.
- Cons: Increases storage use and risks data inconsistencies.

The best approach depends on your specific requirements and available resources. Both strategies have their merit, also storing the same data twice is not wrong at all. Choose based on your application's needs.